# If someone downloaded 600GB , can that be a DOS attack

Tags: linux, security, denial-of-service

Last night someone exploited some vulnerability in my site and then upload a PHP script to my images folder.

I have an Amazon EC2 server with CentOS.

Then the hacker downloaded 600GB and increased my bill.

Can this be a DOS attack? How can I check this?

When hacker was downloading I saw

- CPU usage being 100%
- many apache kworker process running
- I stopped the apache service but data was still being transmitted

I then stopped my instance.

How can I see what happened?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23842/advice-on-what-to-do-after-being-hacked are worth reading. The third thing you mentioned might indicate your system itself was compromised

Comment: If data was transmitted even with Apache being turned off, I'd suggest you set up a new instance.

Comment: @slhck I knew what happened , there was vulnerability in mu site which the hacker exploited. it was this http://www.bugreport.ir/78/exploit.htm . i deleted those scripts and now system is ok. i know it was those scripts. i checked llast modified files in `/var/www/html` and then i got those files. i had `maldetect installed` and it also gave me the report and removed three files but it didn't remove other 2 php files which were also virus. i had to rmeove them and they causing the issue.

Comment: Is it relevant what happened? You already know the vulnerability that was exploited, so you know you can prevent a repeat by killing the server, acquiring a new one, and set that up with the patched Joomla version.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer as your question is unclear as you have changed terminology between the title to the body and you have asked multiple questions without question marks. So unsure if I missed something that was ment to be a question also**

- DDOS stands for `distributed denial-of-service`
- DOS stands for `denial-of-service`

This was not a DDOS attack given the information provided, If you killed you Apache server you kinda performed a `DOS` attack on your self as you denied the service of your webpage.

If the CPU was at 100% usage it probably can be defined as a `DOS` attack as it was unlikely to be servicing pages during this time.

As for finding out what happened check logs and monitoring tools you had active at the time or contact Amazon to see if they can provide anymore insight on the network traffic you attracted.

Comment: how can i contact amazon regarding that. will they help me

Comment: It's unlikely Amazon will investigate this any further. Your web server has been hacked, and that happens every day, probably thousands of times. Get over it and reinstall the machine – especially if you already know what the vulnerability was, why care for what exactly happened?

Comment: If they are billing for the network traffic wouldn't they have an obligation to show that network data? It would really only isolate a time - He will still have to re-install and try and Learn some more about security.

Comment: But i have fixed the vulnerability now. and deleted hacker scripts. can't just i keep my server.

Comment: Did you restore from a back-up then patch or patch over the "Removed" scripts?

Comment: I ahve removed the scripts, but have the amazon sanphots for evryday so i can restore to 3 days old and i dont have any data chnaged betwenn taht time so i can go back to previous snapshot

Comment: Coming from a corporate company with massive server farms all round the world restore a snapshot, Confirm the malicious files are not present and then patch. You have no real idea what happened during this incident play it safe because I have seen what happens when you don't and you don't want that!

Comment: thanks buddy , i followed ur adviced and system is up and running from previous snapshot. AWS made that too easy to restore. what can do prevents these. i winder why maldetect detect half files but not other half