# What steps can I take so that my AWS bill can never go too high in case of hacking?

Tags: linux, security, amazon-web-services

Last night I received an AWS email because of the alarm I had created if my bill exceeds 50$. My month has just started and when I checked the console I saw that 600GB of data was downloaded, as my server was compromised by some vulnerability.

Although I don't have many sites running and I restored from backups, I am more concerned about the money.

I just created a Billing Alarm to check, but it saved me. I was thinking if I didn't know that then, my bill would have been 1000's of dollars.

I want to know if there is any way or steps so that even if my server gets hacked or whatever that my bill does not get high.

I have now created heavy CPU utilization and Max network OUT alarms but is there any other way?

Comment: It would help if you told us what is running on that web server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If someone downloaded 600GB , can that be a DOS attack](http://superuser.com/questions/641201/if-someone-downloaded-600gb-can-that-be-a-dos-attack)

Comment: This is a question better pointed directly to Amazon.  Have you contacted them?

Comment: Use the "Billing Alerts" (which you said you used?): http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/

Comment: @JanDoggen this is not at all a duplicate. different subject. and also its the same person asking the question...